# understanding assembler code for function syscall

Tags: linux-kernel

dump of assembler code for function syscall:

```
0x00007f2db202a3b0 <syscall+0>: mov    %rdi,%rax
0x00007f2db202a3b3 <syscall+3>: mov    %rsi,%rdi
0x00007f2db202a3b6 <syscall+6>: mov    %rdx,%rsi
0x00007f2db202a3b9 <syscall+9>: mov    %rcx,%rdx
0x00007f2db202a3bc <syscall+12>:        mov    %r8,%r10
0x00007f2db202a3bf <syscall+15>:        mov    %r9,%r8
0x00007f2db202a3c2 <syscall+18>:        mov    0x8(%rsp),%r9
0x00007f2db202a3c7 <syscall+23>:        syscall
0x00007f2db202a3c9 <syscall+25>:        cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
0x00007f2db202a3cf <syscall+31>:        jae    0x7f2db202a3d2 <syscall+34>
0x00007f2db202a3d1 <syscall+33>:        retq
0x00007f2db202a3d2 <syscall+34>:        mov    0x28fbbf(%rip),%rcx        #0x7f2db22b9f98
0x00007f2db202a3d9 <syscall+41>:        xor    %edx,%edx
0x00007f2db202a3db <syscall+43>:        sub    %rax,%rdx
0x00007f2db202a3de <syscall+46>:        mov    %edx,%fs:(%rcx)
0x00007f2db202a3e1 <syscall+49>:        or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
0x00007f2db202a3e5 <syscall+53>:        jmp    0x7f2db202a3d1 <syscall+33>
```

End of assembler dump.

can someone tell me what is happening above the line( `0x00007f2db202a3c7 <syscall+23>:        syscall` )

Answer (score 2):

This is conversion from "System V x86_64 calling conventions" to "linux syscall calling conventions".

When you call `syscall` function, compiler treats it as usual function and uses [System V x86_64 calling conventions](http://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions) for passing arguments. Arguments are passed in the following order: rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9, stack. But calling conventions for system calls are different (see `syscall(2)`): system call number goes into rax and arguments go into rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, r9. So, `syscall` converts one calling convention to another one:

```
rdi -> rax (syscall number)
rsi -> rdi (first argument)
rdx -> rsi (second argument)
...
```